# docplex shift end in step_at_end method

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I am solving a scheduling problem in python using docplex where I am assigning start/end to workorder intervals. I also have a cumul function for stock that the workorders produce/consume. I am using step_at_end method to add produced quantity to stock cumul function at the end of the workorder interval variables, but I would like the material to be available after some delay because it takes some time for the material to be ready to use.

```
for wo in workorder_list:
    for quantity, material_id in wo['output']:
        stock[material_id] += model.step_at_end(workorders[wo['id']], quantity)
```

What would be the best way to shift the end for x time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use new intervals for workorders after a given delay and use

```
docplex.cp.modeler.start_at_end(a, b, delay=None)
```

and then use

```
step_at_start
```

with those intervals